# Why does my simulated annealing algorithm generate increasingly worse solutions and converge early?

Tags: algorithm, search, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, simulated-annealing

> **Why does my program generate increasingly worse solutions and converge so early?**

I've been reading up on optimization and various meta-heuristic techniques recently and I recently decided to try and implement simulated annealing as described in [this](http://blog.pluszero.ca/blog/2016/07/17/using-simulated-annealing-to-solve-logic-puzzles/) post.

I believe that I understand the theory well enough.

There is an acceptance probability that is guided by the following function

```
 math.exp(-cost_delta/temp)
```

where the cost delta is the difference between the "cost" of your current solution and the cost of your new randomly generated proposed solution. The greater the cost delta, the lower probability your new solution has of being accepted and as the number of iterations increases and your temperature "cools" and approaches 0, new solutions have a increasingly smaller change of being accepted.

Your cost is determined from some objective function that you either want to minimize or maximize and your objective function will change depending on your problem.

I implemented a simulated annealing function as mentioned in the post and wikipedia:

```
def simulated_annealing(initial_state):
current_state = initial_state
current_cost = cost_of_state(current_state)
temp = 3.0
num_iteration = 0

while current_cost > 0:
    neighbour = get_random_neighbour(current_state)
    neighbour_cost = cost_of_state(neighbour)

    cost_delta = neighbour_cost - current_cost

    if cost_delta <= 0 or random.random() < math.exp(-cost_delta/temp):
        current_state = neighbour
        current_cost = neighbour_cost

    print('current cost: '+str(current_cost))
    print('Num of iterations: '+str(num_iteration))

    num_iteration += 1
    if num_iteration % 500 == 0 and temp > 0.10:
        temp -= 0.10

return current_state, num_iteration
```

as well as a function to get a random neighbor:

```
def get_random_neighbour(current_state):
neighbour = [house[:] for house in current_state]

i = random.randint(0, 4)
mRange = []
mRange.extend(range(0, i))
mRange.extend(range(i+1, 4))
j = random.choice(mRange)
#j = random.randint(0, 4)#.randint(opp1, opp2)

attr_idx = random.randint(0, 4)

neighbour[i][attr_idx] = neighbour[j][attr_idx]
neighbour[j][attr_idx] = neighbour[i][attr_idx]

return neighbour
```

and calculate the cost of the current state based on some objective function:

```
def cost_of_state(state):
cost = 15

for i , h in enumerate(state):
    cost -= sum([
        h[nat] == 'brit' and h[col] == 'red',
        h[nat] == 'swede' and h[ani] == 'dog',
        h[nat] == 'dane' and h[bev] == 'tea',
        i< 4 and h[col] == 'green' and state[i+1][col] == 'white',
        h[col] == 'green' and h[bev] == 'coffee',
        h[cig] == 'pall mall' and h[ani] == 'bird',
        h[col] == 'yellow' and h[cig] == 'dunhill',
        i == 2 and h[bev] == 'milk',
        i == 0 and h[nat] == 'norwegian',
        h[cig] == 'blends' and ((i > 0 and state[i-1][ani] == 'cat') or (i < 4 and state[i+1][ani] == 'cat')),
        h[ani] == 'horse' and ((i > 0 and state[i-1][cig] == 'dunhill') or (i < 4 and state[i-1][cig] == 'dunhill')),
        h[cig] == 'blue master' and h[bev] == 'root beer',
        h[nat] == 'german' and h[cig] == 'prince',
        h[nat] == 'norwegian' and ((i > 0 and state[i-1][col] == 'blue') or (i < 4 and state[i+1][col] == 'blue')),
        h[cig] == 'blends' and ((i > 0 and state[i-1][bev] == 'water') or (i < 4 and state[i+1][bev] == 'water')),
    ])

return cost
```

as well as the code to test/run everything:

```
nationalities = ['dane', 'brit', 'swede', 'norwegian', 'german']
colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'white', 'green', 'blue']
animals = ['horse', 'cat', 'bird', 'fish', 'dog']
beverages = ['water', 'tea', 'milk', 'coffee', 'root beer']
cigars = ['pall mall', 'prince', 'blue master', 'dunhill', 'blends']

attributes = [nationalities, colors, animals, beverages, cigars]
num_houses = 5

nat = 0
col = 1
ani = 2
bev = 3
cig = 4

initial = []

for i in range(0, num_houses):
    initial.append([attr[i] for attr in attributes])

random.seed(100)

solution, iterations = simulated_annealing(initial)

for house in solution:
    print(house)

print('Number of iterations:', iterations)
```

Now, my problem is that when I run everything, I only see a few state changes when I actually run my program. Below you can see the output that I get from the first 10 iterations.

```
current cost: 11
Num of iterations: 0
current cost: 11
Num of iterations: 1
current cost: 11
Num of iterations: 2
current cost: 10
Num of iterations: 3
current cost: 10
Num of iterations: 4
current cost: 10
Num of iterations: 5
current cost: 10
Num of iterations: 6
current cost: 11
Num of iterations: 7
current cost: 11
Num of iterations: 8
current cost: 11
Num of iterations: 9
current cost: 11
Num of iterations: 10
current cost: 11
```

and by the time I get to iteration 65, my solutions are actually getting worse and things seem to stall:

```
urrent cost: 12
Num of iterations: 63
current cost: 12
Num of iterations: 64
current cost: 13
Num of iterations: 65
current cost: 13
```

Comment: Your swap is implemented wrong in your neighbor function.

Comment: (Incidentally, you probably would have noticed that if you looked at what solutions your algorithm is generating.)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for your response. That does answer one of my questions, but now I have the opposite problem. Instead of stalling near the worst solutions(cost=13), it stalls near the best(cost=2 or 1 depending on how I set the temp). I went back and compared my code to the code from the article and I saw that I had part of one of the rules in the cost function written incorrectly, but I still have the same problem just in the opposite direction.

Comment: Well... yeah. That's normal.

Comment: @user2357112 While I know that metahuristic techniques can't guarantee an optimal solution is found, why would the author be able to find the optimal solution while I'm only able to get close?